# How to mock 3rd party server response - Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I'm trying write unit test on a method which has internal server connection (let's say socket connection). My test case is failing and I think the issue is with the way I mock the object. I'm new to unit tests so I have no idea what to next.

This is the method I'm trying to test.

```
class ModuleSpectator {
    
    public long getTotalModules(String server_id){
        Server server = new Server(server_ip);                          // this connects to a 3rd party server.
        ServerState serverState =server.getServerState(server_id);      // resposnse from the server
        return = (long) serverState.getTotalModules();
    }
}
```

This is the unit test.

```
@Test
public void testGetTotalModules(){
    String server_id="ser_01";
    ModuleSpectator moduleSpectator = mock(ModuleSpectator.class);
    Server serverMock = mock(Server.class);
    ServerState serverState =new ServerState();
    serverState.setTotalModules(50);
    
    when(serverMock.getServerState(server_id)).thenReturn(serverState);
    
    assertEquals(50, moduleSpectator.getTotalModules(server_id));
    
}
```

when `moduleSpectator.getTotalModules(server_id)` in **assertEquals()** is executing, it actually trying to connect the 3rd party server. How do I stop this behavior and succefully set and mock the response?

Answer (score 0):

```
Server serverMock = mock(Server.class);
```

does nothing. It will not mock the Server instance created within your `getTotalModules`.

You could add `createServer` method in `ModuleSpectator`  which you could mock then as well, but all you do then is just test if your mocking logic is correct.

Generally, if this code is complete and not a simplified version of what you're doing then it's probably not worthwhile writing a test for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your mock on the real object

Example:

```
Server serverMock = mock(Server.class);
ServerState serverState =new ServerState();
serverState.setTotalModules(50);

when(serverMock.getServerState(server_id)).thenReturn(serverState);

ModuleSpectator moduleSpectator = new ModuleSpectator(serverMock);

assertEquals(50, moduleSpectator.getTotalModules(server_id));
```